# How to convert utf-8 encoding to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I was trying to preprocess some tweet text. The text was in a csv file that has been scraped by tweepy. I am using Jupyter Notebook and let us suppose the it is stored in variable 'p' and the text looks something like this when I just output it using cell output:

> "b'@sarahbea34343 \\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x94 I\\xe2\\x80\\x99m not going in overly optimistic tbh but hey... https://twitter.com/icxdsfdf'"

Instead if I do print(p) in Jupyter then the output is:

> "b'@sarahbea34343 \xf0\x9f\x98\x94 I\xe2\x80\x99m not going in overly optimistic tbh but hey... https://twitter.com/icxdsfdf'"

I checked on the internet and it seemed that this is in byte class utf-8 encoding.
So I tried to decode using ".decode('utf-8')" and it gave an error. The problem that i found out was that as it was stored in csv file the utf-8 encoding was stored as a string and hence this whole tweet was a string. Which means even the backslash is encoded as a string. I don't seem to figure out how do I convert it such that I can remove these emojis and other character's utf encoding?

I have tried multiple things that resulted back in same string again, such as :

> p.encode('ascii','ignore').decode('ascii')
>
> or p.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'ignore')

Comment: You're reading the CSV as bytes, `open(file, 'rb')` or similar. Did you try `open(file, 'r')` which parses as a string instead of a bytes array for you?

Comment: I also tried opening in both 'rb' and 'r' but the backslash is encoded as string only, which the source of all this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text really has been stored like this (so you are reading the file in text mode 'r') you can do this:

```
# Strip leading b and inner quotes
s = "b'@sarahbea34343 \xf0\x9f\x98\x94 I\xe2\x80\x99m not going in overly optimistic tbh but hey... https://twitter.com/icxdsfdf'"[2:-1]

# Encode as latin-1 to get bytes, decode from unicode-escape to unescape 
# the byte expressions (\\xhh -> \xhh), encode as latin-1 again to get 
# bytes again, then finally decode as UTF-8.

new_s = encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
print(new_s)
@sarahbea34343  I’m not going in overly optimistic tbh but hey... https://twitter.com/icxdsfdf
```

Comment: this is not working for me because the string i get is : "b'@sarahbear3333 \\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x94 I\\xe2\\x80\\x99m not going in overly optimistic tbh but hey... https://twitter.com/icxdsfdf". While when I print(str) then the str is shown as "b'@sarahbea34343 \xf0\x9f\x98\x94 I\xe2\x80\x99m not going in overly optimistic tbh but hey... https://twitter.com/icxdsfdf'".

Comment: The encode/decode sequence produces a new string, so you need to assign the result - I've amended the answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: I see double backslashes, so this looks like a job for the "unicode-escape" codec (before the encode-decode round-trip).

Comment: I have edited my question for more clarity. @lenz could you elaborate what do you mean by unicode-escape? I have tried encode-decode sequence from unidecode library but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @lenz, I must have copied the wrong string from the question to work on.